# Can't install Boost 1.59.0 through nuget

Tags: c#, boost, nuget, caffe

I'm trying to install Caffe.clr, which requires boost 1.59.0 as a dependency.  This is failing to install:

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'boost.1.59.0' with respect to project 'Project', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5,Profile=Unity Full v3.5'
Gathering dependency information took 2.08 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'boost.1.59.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'boost.1.59.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'boost.1.59.0'
Retrieving package 'boost 1.59.0' from 'nuget.org'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'boost.1.59.0' does not exist in project 'ParticleFilter2'
Package 'boost.1.59.0' does not exist in folder 'c:\Project'
Executing nuget actions took 2.96 sec
Install-Package : Could not install package 'boost 1.59.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5,Profile=Unity Full v3.5', but the package does not contain 
any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package boost -Version 1.59.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

I have tried lots of targets, including .Net 3.5 vanilla, .Net 4.6, and .Net 4.7.1, all give roughly the same error.  Why is this happening?  How can I install boost/caffe?

Comment: "https://github.com/sergey-shandar/getboost" it writes you need to manually  download and build the C++ boost libraries

Comment: What writes that?  Anyway, I can download a newer version of boost through nuget just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can install native packages to `NETFramework,Version=v3.5,Profile=Unity Full v3.5`